# Run a Windows Docker container in an Azure VNet and authenticate to Azure resources with the Managed Identity assigned to the host

Tags: docker, vnet

I've an *Azure VM* deployed in an `Azure VNet` and with a `Managed Identity` assigned to it.

I've also installed in that VM *Docker Desktop App* and would like to run a container. This container has to be deployed in the same VNet where the host is and use the same Managed Identity to authenticate to some Azure resources.

If the container was LinuxOs-based, as far as I can see this task can be easily achieved by running the container in the `host` network. But, unfortunately, that is not available for Windows container.

So, how can I achieve the same if my Docker container is Windows-based? Should I create a new network that 'emulates' the host's one?